# What is the lifetime of "vscode.window"in Visual Studio Code extension API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

Are there any lifetime guarantees for vscode.window object https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window ?

Is it a singleton or could there be multiple different windows during a single extension lifetime which is the period between activate() and deactivate()?

I am mostly interested in this in the context of `createOutputChannel()` function - what happens if the parent window somehow dies, would it invalidate the `LogOutputChannel` instance that the function returns?